# How to check the Boolean condition from the another Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have three `DF` first is base `df` second is behavior `df` and third is rule `df`

```
Base df:
+---+----+------+
| ID|Name|Salary|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   A|   100|
|  2|   B|   200|
|  3|   C|   300|
|  4|   D|  1000|
|  5|   E|   500|
+---+----+------+

Behavior DF:
+----+---------+------+
|S.NO|Operation|Points|
+----+---------+------+
|   1|  a AND b|   100|
|   2|   a OR b|   200|
|   3|otherwise|     0|
+----+---------+------+

Rule DF:
+----+-----+------+------------+-----+
|RULE|Table|   col|   operation|value|
+----+-----+------+------------+-----+
|   a| Base|Salary|       equal| 1000|
|   b| Base|Salary|Greater Than|  500|
+----+-----+------+------------+-----+
```

I want to calculate the reward point of every person and add the column in the base df by the name of reward and check the condition in behavior df If a AND b is true it will assign 100 Point or If a OR b is True so 200 points will assign otherwise 0 points will assign where a or b condition in the Rule Table

```
Expected DF
 +---+----+------+------+
| ID|Name|Salary|Reward|
+---+----+------+------+
|  1|   A|   100|     0|
|  2|   B|   200|     0|
|  3|   C|   300|     0|
|  4|   D|  1000|   200|
|  5|   E|   500|     0|
+---+----+------+------+
```

Comment: Are there in total only these two rules in Rule df or is it more bigger? And behaviour df will also contain only these three s.no?

Comment: No temporary there are only three rule in the table

Comment: You might have to join all the rules and behaviour table rows to each row of the base df. Depending on the total size and all available rules, we can decide whether we need to treat the behavior and rules tables as pyspark dataframe or not. Can you tell the size of both the tables and how many rules will be there?

Comment: Also, does each S.No in behavior df corresponds to each ID in base df?

Comment: Yes, because AND or OR  will both condition is  true so In case of maximum point will assign to that person

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this approach -

I have to make slight changes in `Rule` and `Behavior` dataframe. Stored operations as logic ("==") instead of string ("equal").

```
Base = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'A',100),(2,'B',200),(3,'C',300),(4,'D',1000),(5,'E',500)],['ID','Name','Salary'])

Behavior = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'df.rule_a & df.rule_b',100),(2,'df.rule_a | df.rule_b',200),(3,'otherwise',0)],['SNo','Operation','Points'])

Rule = spark.createDataFrame([(1,'Base','Salary','==',1000),(2,'Base','Salary','>',500)],['RULE','Table','col','operation','value'])

Base.show()

#+---+----+------+
#| ID|Name|Salary|
#+---+----+------+
#|  1|   A|   100|
#|  2|   B|   200|
#|  3|   C|   300|
#|  4|   D|  1000|
#|  5|   E|   500|
#+---+----+------+

Behavior.show()

#+---+---------------------+------+
#|SNo|           Operation |Points|
#+---+---------------------+------+
#|  1|df.rule_a & df.rule_b|   100|
#|  2|df.rule_a | df.rule_b|   200|
#|  3|           otherwise |     0|
#+---+---------------------+------+

Rule.show()

#+----+-----+------+---------+-----+
#|RULE|Table|   col|operation|value|
#+----+-----+------+---------+-----+
#|   1| Base|Salary|       ==| 1000|
#|   2| Base|Salary|        >|  500|
#+----+-----+------+---------+-----+
```

Prepare logic for rules stored in `Rules` dataframe

For dynamically preparing rules, you can run a `for loop` over `Rule` dataframe and pass the iteration number to filter transaformation and Rule variable.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import  col,concat,lit

rule_a = Rule.filter("RULE == 1").select(concat(col("Table"), lit("['"),  col("col"), lit("']"), lit(" "),  col("Operation"), col("Value"))).collect()[0][0]

rule_b = Rule.filter("RULE == 2").select(concat(col("Table"), lit("['"),  col("col"), lit("']"), lit(" "),  col("Operation"), col("Value"))).collect()[0][0]
```

Add boolean result of rules execution to dataframe

```
df = Base.withColumn("rule_a", eval(rule_a)).withColumn("rule_b", eval(rule_b))

df.show()

#+---+----+------+------+------+
#| ID|Name|Salary|rule_a|rule_b|
#+---+----+------+------+------+
#|  1|   A|   100| false| false|
#|  2|   B|   200| false| false|
#|  3|   C|   300| false| false|
#|  4|   D|  1000|  true|  true|
#|  5|   E|   500| false| false|
#+---+----+------+------+------+
```

store behavior and corresponding points from `Behavior` dataframe to variables

For dynamically preparing variables, you can run a `for loop` over Behavior dataframe and pass the iteration number as variable to filter transformation and column name.

```
behavior1 = Behavior.filter("SNo==1").select( col("Operation")).collect()[0][0]
behavior1_points = Behavior.filter("SNo==1").select( col("Points")).collect()[0][0]

behavior2 = Behavior.filter("SNo==2").select( col("Operation")).collect()[0][0]
behavior2_points = Behavior.filter("SNo==2").select( col("Points")).collect()[0][0]

behavior3 = Behavior.filter("SNo==3").select( col("Operation")).collect()[0][0]
behavior3_points = Behavior.filter("SNo==3").select( col("Points")).collect()[0][0]
```

Final solution

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit,when,col,greatest 

df\
  .withColumn("b1", eval(behavior1))\
  .withColumn("b2", eval(behavior2))\
           .select('*'
                   ,greatest(when(col('b1') == 'true',lit(behavior1_points)).otherwise(0)
                             ,when(col('b2') == 'true',lit(behavior2_points)).otherwise(0)
                             ,lit(behavior3_points)).alias('point')).drop('rule_a','rule_b','b1','b2').show()

#+---+----+------+-----+
#| ID|Name|Salary|point|
#+---+----+------+-----+
#|  1|   A|   100|    0|
#|  2|   B|   200|    0|
#|  3|   C|   300|    0|
#|  4|   D|  1000|  200|
#|  5|   E|   500|    0|
#+---+----+------+-----+
```

Comment: can you convert this code dynamic Let's suppose if new behavior and new rule is added in my dataframe so I need to change my code but I don't want to change the code just add the rule and behaviour and code remain same

Comment: you can run a loop and increment the sequence number of behavior through each iteration and then dynamically prepare final calculation using those variables.

Comment: I am new in this domain can you do it...?? It would be very helpful for me