# How the check the Boolean condition between the column in Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the Dataframe I want to check the condition in between the column:

```
+---+----+------+---------+------+
| ID|Name|Salary|Operation|Points|
+---+----+------+---------+------+
|  1|   A| 10000|  a AND b|   100|
|  1|   A| 10000|   a OR b|   200|
|  1|   A| 10000|otherwise|     0|
|  2|   B|   200|  a AND b|   100|
|  2|   B|   200|   a OR b|   200|
|  2|   B|   200|otherwise|     0|
|  3|   C|   700|  a AND b|   100|
|  3|   C|   700|   a OR b|   200|
|  3|   C|   700|otherwise|     0|
|  4|   D|  1000|  a AND b|   100|
|  4|   D|  1000|   a OR b|   200|
|  4|   D|  1000|otherwise|     0|
|  5|   E|   650|  a AND b|   100|
|  5|   E|   650|   a OR b|   200|
|  5|   E|   650|otherwise|     0|
+---+----+------+---------+------+
```

Where:

```
a='salary==1000'
b='salary>500'
```

If the operation will true so points will assign and new column will add in the dataframe by name reward
for eg 
if first entry occur A having salary is 10000 check the condition a if salary is equal to 1000 and salary is greater then 500 so `a AND b` false so 0 point will asign
result:

```
+---+----+------+------+
| ID|Name|Salary|Reward|
+---+----+------+------+
|  1|   A| 10000|   200|
|  2|   B|   200|     0|
|  3|   C|   700|   200|
|  4|   D|  1000|   200|
|  5|   E|   650|   200|
+---+----+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can piece something together with a [filter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) expression and a [groupby](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [
(  1,   'A', 10000,  'a AND b',   100),
(  1,   'A', 10000,   'a OR b',   200),
(  1,   'A', 10000,'otherwise',     0),
(  2,   'B',   200,  'a AND b',   100),
(  2,   'B',   200,   'a OR b',   200),
(  2,   'B',   200,'otherwise',     0),
(  3,   'C',   700,  'a AND b',   100),
(  3,   'C',   700,   'a OR b',   200),
(  3,   'C',   700,'otherwise',     0),
(  4,   'D',  1000,  'a AND b',   100),
(  4,   'D',  1000,   'a OR b',   200),
(  4,   'D',  1000,'otherwise',     0),
(  5,   'E',   650,  'a AND b',   100),
(  5,   'E',   650,   'a OR b',   200),
(  5,   'E',   650,'otherwise',     0)]

columns = ['ID','Name','Salary','Operation','Points']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

df.filter(
          (df.Operation.contains('AND')        & (df.Salary == 1000) & (df.Salary > 500))    |
          (df.Operation.contains('OR')         & ((df.Salary == 1000) | (df.Salary > 500)))  |
          df.Operation.contains('otherwise') 
          ).groupBy('ID', 'Name', 'Salary').agg(F.max('Points').alias('Rewards')).show()
```

Output:

```py
+---+----+------+-------+ 
| ID|Name|Salary|Rewards| 
+---+----+------+-------+ 
|  1|   A| 10000|    200| 
|  2|   B|   200|      0| 
|  3|   C|   700|    200| 
|  5|   E|   650|    200| 
|  4|   D|  1000|    200| 
+---+----+------+-------+
```

Please also have a look at a similar question and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56416679/how-to-check-the-boolean-condition-from-the-another-dataframe/56428540#56428540) of Shan.